# Purchased an Elegoo 3.5" TFT Display and getting white screen after instructions

Tags: touchscreen, screen

I recently purchased an Elegoo 3.5" TFT Display for my Raspberry Pi 2 B+. 
I plugged it in (correctly) and it booted to a white screen as expected.

I then followed the tutorial outlined in this file: [Tutorial provided by vendor Elegoo](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y6ia0v7h7v7a7cr/3.5inch%20touch%20screen%20user%20manual%EF%BC%88Arduino-English%EF%BC%89V1.00.2017.05.17.pdf?dl=0)

All of the commands executed as described but on reboot the screen remains white. Can't make heads or tails and research proves false because it is for a different screen. Any ideas anyone?

EDIT: Forgot to specify I followed the instructions under 2.2 "Using Raspberry Official System"

Comment: I got it to work with the provided image in section 2.1. Annoying that I had to format.

Comment: I have the same problem since a month...I have asked Elegoo about the problem, answer : "OK, we send you an other screen..."
So the problem is still here :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eureka !! I've followed to install a good driver for this screen :)
After many tries and search, I've found this tutorial :

http://www.waveshare.com/wiki/3.5inch_RPi_LCD_(A)

I've upgraded the firmware and raspbian before installing the driver, and after reboot, BINGO !! I just had to launched "LCD35-show 180" to have display in good orientation.

Hope that it will help you guys !